# Finding Compound Words in A Text File of 150,000+ Words

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, cpu-word, trie

I have to find all of the compound words in a text file. This file contains almost 200,000 words and I am trying to implement this in the least amount of time.

So for example, the text file contains the words fire, house, and firehouse. Firehouse would be considered a compound word and would be added to a different text file displayed as "fire-house".

What is the best data structure or implementation that I can use to find all of these compound words in the fastest time?

Any tips or help is appreciated.

I've tried doing some stuff, but when I run the program, it takes forever.

I need an algorithm that runs in linear time.

Comment: Scan through the wordlist: add each words to [a trie structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), if the word matches an existing trie prefix when added then add the remainder suffix substring to a new set. Then after the entire wordlist is injested, test each remainder suffix to see if that suffix has a word as a prefix. Repeat for remaining suffices.

Comment: I sketched something out in Linqpad and it's able to chew through a 400,000-entry `words.txt` file in about 2.2 seconds: https://i.imgur.com/rM0AB64.png and finds results like "aerohydrotherapy" -> "aero" + "hydro" + "therapy". Neat.

Comment: @OP You tagged `trie`, so why haven't you mentioned it in your post?

Comment: Here's the Linqpad version I sketched out: https://gist.github.com/daiplusplus/d9f0df6ecd17657e382f90213db3db71 - fun little mental exercise, that was (a lot of the results at the bottom kinda suck, but that's because the `words.txt` file I used contained a lot of non-words, grumble)

Comment: The following algorithm is very simiple and reasonably efficient
taking O(number-characters) operations. The code and build
instructions are on [GitHub](https://github.com/cpp-core/so.git) in
the directory `76178746`.

Comment: I wonder if you could feed `fgrep` a dictionary, run it against your text, and then post-process the output. That's the first thing I'd try. I just don't know how well fgrep would handle a few hundred thousand search strings.

Comment: RandomBits: change your code line:
if (words.contains(w1) and words.contains(w2)) 
To
if (words.contains(w1+w2)) 
And then your code will work